# SandCastle MREFBuilder barfing on Crystal Reports XI

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, sandcastle, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to use SandCastle to generate some help documentation for my latest project.  Everything worked fine for my utility project, but when I try to use it with my main project it barfs on Crystal Reports.

```
Generating reflection information...
[c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe]
GenerateRefInfo:
  MrefBuilder (v2.6.10621.1)
  Copyright c Microsoft 2006
  Info: Loaded 1 assemblies for reflection and 0 dependency assemblies.
MREFBUILDER : error : Unresolved assembly reference: BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder (BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder, Version=14.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304) required by CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
    Last step completed in 00:00:03.1875
-------------------------------

SHFB: Error BE0043: Unexpected error detected in last build step.  See output above for details.
```

Does anyone know how I can just completely exclude all of the Crystal Reports files, or some type of fix?

Answer (score 1):

There is now a permanent fix in the latest Sandcastle to process Dot Net projects that include Crystal Reports - please see the post http://geekswithblogs.net/TATWORTH/archive/2012/10/12/sandcastle-help-file-builder---october-2010-release.aspx

The latest Sandcastle download is at http://shfb.codeplex.com/releases/view/92191

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer - but i've just come across this while researching the same issue:

http://www.visualstudiodev.com/developer-documentation-help-system/sandcastle-issue-error-unresolved-assembly-reference-14559.shtml

Stephen

EDIT:
I've given up on this - and although the Sandcastle developer Eric Woodruff was very helpful via email, the only way i can think that this could be fixed is if Sandcastle had some more graceful exception handling. Without this, i can't document my project with Sandcastle.